# Can't connect to localhost

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am learning PHP and am working on a script that connects to my DB and pulls some data.

The website I have running on my localhost is a PHP driven CMS.

A segment of the script is here

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER','myname');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD','somepass123');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME','sitename');


// make the db connection
$dbc = @mysqli_connect('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME')
    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

When I load a page that draws on the PHP I receive the following error where the output data is meant to be:

> Could not connect to mysql: Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (1)

I did some research on SO and some googling around. A suspect issue could be that DB_HOST is defined elsewhere. Is that plausible? I'm not experienced enough to know if this is the right path.

I did find this in the config/database.php file, I'm not sure if it's relevant:

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'benchmark' => TRUE,
    'persistent' => FALSE,
    'connection' => array(
        'type' => 'mysqli',
        'user' => 'myname',
        'pass' => 'somepass123',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => FALSE,
        'socket' => FALSE,
        'database' => 'sitename',
```

How would I approach figuring out next steps? Is this a common error? Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Try `@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)`, since you defined them as variables, it should be without the quotes.

Comment: Ignore this, completely wrong info, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop the single quotes around your constants:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
         OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

You should also refrain from using `@` in front of functions. If you wish to suppress errors, use proper error handling.